# Creating an ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I want to create an `Asp.net Core` project with `Visual Studio 2017` Community but the Solutions explorer says that I have *(0 projects).*

I tried selecting an empty project, web application, web application (Model-View-Controller) but the Solution explorer still displays (0 projects).

When I go-to Debug I see the **"Attach to Process"** option. There is no option to start of course since I have no projects.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to use **Visual Studio Installer** to install required web-development components?

Comment: Try following this guide, it's for VS 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-aspnet-core?view=vs-2017

Comment: @picolino: yes i installed the required components and initially i created an asp.net project and run successfully. To my surprise this time VS IDE its not creating any projects.

Comment: @Peter B: okay let me visit the link you sent

Comment: @Peter B: i followed the instructions and the problem remains

Comment: is there any reason to use an outdated visual studio version? Particularly if you use community, 2019 is as expensive as 2017 - free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed everything correctly? To verify this, open a normal cmd and just type 'dotnet'

Only if the command runs, printing out information about how to use dotnet, you're good to go.

Have you installed the correct .NET SDK? What version of it? Make sure the version is compatible with the version of visual studio you have installed.

Follow this link for step by step setup instructions: 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-net-core-on-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: i have run the command: dotnet and prints out how to use dotnet. I installed .NET Core 2.1 and i am running Visual Studio 2017. Let me try to uninstall 2.1 and try again.

Comment: The problem has been fixed. What i did is uninstall the .NET CORE update and Visual Studio is now running the version that come preinstalled in VS 2017 Community. After the uninstall i am still running 2.1 but now its working fine. Thank you all for your assistance and thank you Vishav for bringing it to my mind that it may be compatibility issues. So uninstalling the .NET Core update fixed the issue. Maybe VS reverted to default.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the same problem, but I had the same issue during College once but this time I had the support for the web components, so I went back to the installation and repaired it. It downloaded the missing files and it worked again and it took a while.

Let me know if that works or not.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: My internet data is very low so i have not yet tried your solution.